# How to select dropdown option when the same dropdown option is selected in other dropwown?

Tags: jquery

Here I’ve 2 dropdowns

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

2 different IDs for each dropdown: how do I select the same dropdown value/option which is selected in either of the dropdowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly...

```js
$(document).on('change', '[name="cars"]', function(){
  $('[name="cars"]').val( $(this).val() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Suppose if there're 5 options in 1st dropdowns & 4 options in 2nd dropdowns, how do I show a error message saying something like "Please select correct options"?

Comment: )) Ok: [codepen](https://codepen.io/imhvost/pen/rNqKooZ)

Comment: In the 2nd dropdown instead of alerting the error message, is that possible to choose the 1st option "Please-Select" in Dropdown when "Audi" option is selected? [codepen](https://codepen.io/mylospykar/pen/MWPBpap) I mean when "Audi" is selected in 1st Dropdown, then 2nd dropdown should set to "default/Please-Select" option.